# Formato da data e hora na conversão xls/csv

Tags: batch, vbscript

tenho um codigo que funciona, no entanto preciso de ajuda no formato da data. Na conversão de xls para csv converte a data para mm/dd/aaaa e hora em h:mm e eu queria que fosse dd-mm-yyyy e a hora em hh:mm. O que preciso no meu código?

exemplo da conversão data e hora: 5/28/2018 0:15 e eu precisava que você fizesse assim: 28-05-2018 00:15

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
oBook.SaveAs dest_file, 3
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(dest_file, 1)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, " ", ";")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(dest_file, 2)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText    
objFile.Close
```

Comment: Ele está usando o formato de Data/Hora configurado no painel de controle do computador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de

```
oBook.SaveAs dest_file, 3
```

faça assim:

```
oBook.Worksheets(0) _
    .Columns("letra da coluna que tem a data/hora a mudar") _
    .NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"
```